# With Gradle 2.12 (for Java), how can download source files if and only if 'build'?

Tags: java, gradle

I want to make a gradle script which downloads source code via internet when and only when you build (e.g. not when you 'gradle claen').

I can basically make it possible and the downloading is done only there is no  directory 'src'. If I make a task that downloads the source codes, then maybe the downloading is not done when you 'gradle clean'.
but I want to make the script download the codes when you 'gradle build'
thats why I write scripts which downloads the codes in ccompileJava...
but If I do so, if you do 'gradle clean' when you have no a directory 'src',
gradle downloads the codes and then deletes it...

How can I make a script satisfying my wish...?

below is the script part related to the question.

```
compileJava {
if (!new File('src').exists()){
    tasks.downloadZipFile.execute()
    tasks.downloadAndUnzipFile.execute()
    file('downloaded/src').renameTo('src')
    delete 'downloaded'
}
}


clean { delete 'src' }
```

Comment: compileJava {
 if (!new File('src').exists()){
  tasks.downloadZipFile.execute()
  tasks.downloadAndUnzipFile.execute()
  file('downloaded/src').renameTo('src')
  delete 'downloaded'
 }
}
clean { delete 'src' }

Comment: Not in comments. In your question, properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code executes during the configuration phase. So it's executed whatever task you execute.

It should instead execute in the execution phase, once gradle has decided which tasks to run, in which order. Create a task, and make compileJava depend on that task, since it must execute **before** compileJava:

```
task downloadSources << {
    ...
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn downloadSources
}
```

Note the `<<` in downloadSources. That means that the closure following is executed as part of the task execution, and not as part of its configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is quite an answer that I wanted.